# Can I set a gradient as the background of a Scaffold?

Tags: flutter

I don't see the option in the Scaffold parameters, and the `backgroundColor` one only accepts a `Color`. Is there a possibility to set a gradient as the background of a Scaffold, **without having to use a Container with decoration**?

Comment: Wrap your Scaffold in a DecoratedBox with a gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You can add DecoratedBox or Container as the body and give the gradient color in that. For an example,

```
return Scaffold(
  body: DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: gradientColors,
      ),
    ),child: ......Your code........,
  ),
);
```

colors is a list of colours. So you give whatever colour you like. This will show you the colours in the 1st to last order. For an example,

```
[
const Colors.blue,
const Colors.white,
const Colors.red,];
```

Or you can define a list of colors and call that list of colors using the name of list. In the above example, I've given the color "gradientColors", which is a list. Here is how you can create a list of Colors:

```
List<Color> gradientColors = [
const Colors.blue,
const Colors.white,
const Colors.red,];
```

After creating a list like this, all you have to do is call this list in your property.

Hope this help. Ask me if you need anything related to flutter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: **NO**. It's not possible to set a gradient in a Scaffold directly, without using additional widgets.

The other answers to this post are the only solutions.